# Junk Mails appear more then once in a shared mailbox

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook-2010

In our company we are using Exchange 2007 and Outlook 2010 to access shared mailboxes on the Exchange Server.

I noticed that junk mails appear that amount of times in the junk mail folder, as users are connected to the mailbox.

I didn't find this problem anywhere but a customer of us has the same problem so I thought that may be a known issue.

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty simple - more than one Outlook (2010) is permanently connected to the mailbox and the process of moving a mail to junk is copy, paste and remove from inbox afterwards. In the meanwhile the other Outlook also copied and pasted the mail.